# No such file or directory when mounting a .vdi VM

Tags: fedora, mount, virtual-machine, qemu

i have a Virtual Box VM with Fedora installed and it's filesystem went to read-only mode. I have now to recover some files from there so in the past i mounted the image in the host Ubuntu machine as described in the top answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/19430/mount-a-virtualbox-drive-image-vdi It always worked fine, but now i have an error when executing: `sudo mount /dev/nbd0p2 /mnt`

The error: `mount: /mnt: mount(2) system call failed: No such file or directory.`

Clearly `/mnt`  is there and it works when mounting `ndb0p1` . Any suggestion?